# How do i suppress errors using PHPMailer (mail is sent and received successfully in spite of error msg)?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I'm using the following code to send mails:

```
<?php
  
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $receiving_email_address = 'somebody@somedomain.com';

  

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 

    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
    $mail->Port = 587 ; //465 or 587

     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    //Authentication
    $mail->Username = "someaddress@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "********";

    
    $msg = "From: ".$_POST['name']."\nEmail: ".$_POST['email']."\nMessage: ".$_POST['message'];
    $msg = nl2br($msg);

    //Set Params
    $mail->SetFrom("sinhat@gmail.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("tushar+forms@bluetide.co");
    $mail->Subject = "Form with title: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body = $msg;


    
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Error while sending Email.";
      var_dump($mail);
    } else {
      echo "Email sent successfully";
    }  
?>
```

This is being invoked from the following HTML code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="name">Your Name</label>
      input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
      <label for="name">Your Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group mt-3">
     <label for="name">Subject</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group mt-3">
     <label for="name">Message</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" required></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="my-3">
    <div class="loading">Loading</div>
    <div class="error-message">An error occured but your msg has been sent</div>
    <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
 </div>
 <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

The mails are coming through but I get this strange error code block on my webpage [(screenshot also attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPgAh.png):

Error: 2022-06-09 08:34:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2022-06-09 08:34:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2022-06-09 08:34:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2022-06-09 08:34:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2022-06-09 08:34:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden] 2022-06-09 08:34:55 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden] 2022-06-09 08:34:55 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 2022-06-09 08:34:55 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 9 Jun 2022 08:34:53 +0000 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: xxx@xxx.com 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: xxxxx@gmail.com 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Form with title: test 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: 8tGuy8dJRkaxDXE6ocPdUX6bz3uyqNuOPNTSIVOsM@localhost 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.0 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: test
2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Email: test@gmail.com
2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message: test 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: 2022-06-09 08:34:56 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 2022-06-09 08:34:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT Email sent successfully

This occurs whether I run the code on my local PHP server or if I push to heroku.

Since the mails come through is there a way to suppress this error message?

Edit: as droopsnoot pointed out setting smtpdebug to 0 reduces the verobisty of the error but I still get the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAvMY.png) "Error: Email sent successfully"

Comment: I don't see that as an error message, it's clearly some sort of debug output. Perhaps the line `$mail->SMTPDebug=1` is to blame?

Comment: Thank you! It does help partially but now I get this strange output: Error: Email sent successfully 

Comment: Are you using JS/AJAX to send the message? Maybe that code is adding the "Error" text into the output? It doesn't seem to come from the PHP

Comment: I think that's probably the case, as the original long message was also prefixed with "Error:"

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, if you enable debug output, you get debug output. Delete this line:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

The `Email sent successfully` output is your own code!

```
echo "Email sent successfully";
```

If you don't want it to display that, delete that line too.

Comment: I think the OP is now actually confused about why "Error:" is prepended to the "Email sent successfully" text. Which isn't clear from the code provided. Hence my comment about AJAX